# Error ORA-01821 "date format not recognized"

Tags: oracle

I am trying to alter the session date format to "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:FF6"

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:FF6'
```

is what I'm trying to use and it's giving me the error ORA-01821 "date format not recognized".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

The Oracle `DATE` type only has second-level precision (as opposed to, say, microsecond-level precision), so date formats don't support the `FF` notation. If you really want microseconds appended, you can write:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:"000000"';
```

Alternatively, maybe you actually wanted to set the default *timestamp* format? If so:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:FF6';
```

Comment: Well, it's for homework and I would like to assume that my instructor would know what he's doing..but here's the whole question: "5. Change the date format for the current session so it shows the time in “YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FF6” format. Then, write a SELECT statement that retrieves the date_added column from the Products table after it has been converted to Eastern Standard Time (EST) with est_time as the column name."  As written, i can't do that because it gives me the "format code appears twice" error.  Not sure why I'm supposed to append the FF6.

Comment: Re: instructor knowing what he's doing: Honestly, both mistakes (specifying sub-second formatting in a date format, using `MM` for minutes) seem pretty minor to me. I've probably made each of those mistakes at least five times. Of course, ideally he would have tried out his instructions before distributing them; but, eh, instructors are people, too.

Comment: Clearly the instructions are wrong. Re: assessment of the instructor, I hope you are not paying too much for this instruction. Sloppy English teacher - OK. Sloppy IT instructor? I am less understanding than @ruakh; OK if his grammar is not perfect (would be inexcusable for the English teacher). Pity you have to put up with him/her.